# How to support more HTTPS Ciphers?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-errors, cipher

I am debugging an IoT device that I am making. I am having it try and connect to my website (EC2 hosted) over HTTPS. The device is running into an issue negotiating the TLS handshake, and it is throwing a Handshake Failure (40). The IoT device supports the following Cipher Suites.

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
```

How can I make my server support one of these Cipher Suites? Do I need a different SSL cert? My current one is from https://www.sslforfree.com/

My website is https://sniffergps.com/ and https://app.sniffergps.com/ (Amazon API Gateway)

**Termination details:**
For app.sniffergps.com, I am using AWS API Gateway, custom domain. I just input my certificate details.

For sniffergps.com, its Elastic beanstalk, so the certificate is on the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

[SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sniffergps.com&s=52.206.157.196&latest) says TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA is supported. Otherwise you can go into the ELB ad update the cipher settings to support more options.